# System.exception Cant resolve name on element xaml

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.ios

hey guys i'm new at Xamarin so please keep that in mind! :)

Im running into a problem with using x:Reference slider, im aware there are similar questions on stackoverflow but they are much more complicated then this one

here is the full xaml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
x:Class="exampleApp.QuotesPage">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
    <Button x:Name="next" Text="next" Clicked= "Handle_Clicked">
</Button> 


<Label Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference slider},  Path=Value,  
StringFormat='Value is {0:F2}'}" />


            <Slider Maximum="50" Minimum="12"/>
        <Label Text="QUOTE" x:Name ="quoteLabel"></Label> 
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

here is where the error is occurring :

```
 <Label Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference slider},  Path=Value,  
StringFormat='Value is {0:F2}'}" />
```

please help!! thank you

Answer (score 6):

The `Slider` that you are binding into the label's text property does not a `x:Name` attached to it thus the `Label` is throwing the error that is can not find the name `slider`:

```
<StackLayout>
    <Button x:Name="next" Text="next" Clicked= "Handle_Clicked" />
    <Label Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference slider},  Path=Value,  StringFormat='Value is {0:F2}'}" />
    <Slider x:Name="slider" Maximum="50" Minimum="12" />
    <Label Text="QUOTE" x:Name="quoteLabel" />
</StackLayout>
```

FYI: You can catch these type of error at compile time vs. runtime by applying the Xaml Compiler to an individual page:

```
[XamlCompilation (XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
```

Or at the assembly level to compile all the XAML pages:

```
[assembly: XamlCompilation (XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
```

Re: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xamlc/

Comment: Thank you so much for that! Also where would you put this code to make it catch errors at run time? Ive tried to find a preferences folder or something like that to no avail, i'm on mac visual studio.

Comment: @ZackJensen117 The Xamarin link at the bottom of my answer shows code samples of how to use these `XamlCompilation` attributes, to apply to an page individual page, you place it in the code-behind `.cs` file above the class definition, for the assembly level, you can place it in any file, but I would recommend something like the `Resource/AssemblyInfo.cs` as there are assembly level references in there already...